Fastest way to sample weighted random index in C++?
I am implementing an algorithm which requires taking thousands of random samples from an array of 100 integers.
std::vector<int> weight_vector(100);

I would like to understand how I can improve the running time of my current approach, as it is the main bottleneck in my overall algorithm. Consider the following code which times weighted random sampling.
// let's just populate weight_vector somehow: 1, 2, ..., 99
iota(weight_vector.begin(), weight_vector.end(), 0);

std::discrete_distribution<int> weighted_dist = std::discrete_distribution<>(
    weight_vector.begin(),
    weight_vector.end()
);

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (int n = 1; n <= 10000; n++)
{
    int random_index = weighted_dist(generator);

    // do something with randomly sampled index...
}

auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = end-start;

std::cout << ms_double.count() << "ms" << std::endl;

The running time of this loop is around 2.9ms. This is currently unacceptably high, and bringing this down to an order of magnitude of 0.1ms would be a great success. Is there any obvious way I can do this? Or perhaps a more efficient way to generate my random indices?
I suspect this might be possible because instead setting int random_index = rand()%100; gives the loop a running time of less than 0.1ms. Of course, this is the wrong distribution, however it leads me to suspect sampling random bits need not be as time consuming as the first approach (e.g. can I get a weighted random bit through one or more calls to rand()?). I am not concerned about the "quality" of the randomness, and if I was sampling a uniform index, rand() would be entirely sufficient.
I would like to consider this before I turn towards parallelisation (all of my loop iterations are independent and the end result is basically an average of the loop values, so in theory this would be possible). If I eventually go this way, would parallelisation be feasible? Or are running times on the order of ms below the threshold at which the overheads of thread management begin to dominate?
Thank you very much for your help, and I apologise for the vague nature of my question. I am quite inexperienced with C++ and 'low-level' programming, so please excuse me.

Probably a memory/speed tradeoff is needed. Say you want index 7 to be 3 times as likely you add 7 three times to the input indices. After that you can randomly pick an index (and use some very fast psuedo random generation something like xorshift

First things first: do you compile with optimisations enabled?

@Yksisarvinen Please could you elaborate on this? I probably did not :)

Tactical note: Be very careful using high_resolution_clock for timing. It is specified to favour resolution over clock stability and you can sometimes find yourself on systems where to get that higher resolution the clock does stupid things like jump backward in time. At the very least, you need to make sure the clock is "steady" (call is_steady) and then use an alternative clock. Generally you're better off just using steady_clock directly.

Most compilers build for debug by default. gcc and clang have a variety of -O options, typically you want -O2 for a reasonable set of optimisations or -O3 for more aggressive optimisations. In Visual Studio first thing would be to build Release target, I don't know specific options.

@Yksisarvinen Ah, yes, I am building with cmake and I have these flags enabled.

Parallelizing the loop using multiple threads is fine here on a mainstream PC since the overhead of creating threads is generally below hundreds of µs. If you use OpenMP which is able to parallelize the loop very easily (using just #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(generator)) and recycling threads, then the overhead should be smaller than dozens of µs. It can however be significantly higher on servers with many cores though (e.g. typically ~10x bigger). So it depends of the target platform which is not provided.

If you are randomly sampling 10000 times from just 100 numbers why not just apply the distribution weighting to the results of the 100 possible answers! Or is there something about the problem that you haven't described.

@JérômeRichard Sure there is a O(1) sampling, called Alias sampling. See my answer for details.

I guess the problem is more about the generator object, whose definition is not visible. Did you compare for different engines? e.g. std::minstd_rand against std::mt19937_64? <random> provides a dozen of generators; you can implement your own too.

@Red.Wave I have tried all of the listed engines. The difference is not huge, and I'm using std::mt19937_64 which is consistently about 20% faster than the others. I guess I could implement my own simply using rand(), sacrificing the quality of randomness for speed?

There are a bunch of other possible tests. Using rand as generator and uniform_int_distribution instead of modulus. Just to clearly identify the bottleneck. I would also preallocate a vector of 10000 elements and output to file, to make sure compiler doesn't optimize out the random number generation.

Could you please tell us about platform/compiler?

You should look into Alias sampling. This method requires some preparations steps, and uses a bit more memory. But sampling itself is very fast, O(1).
There are several implementations in C++ and other languages, e.g. https://github.com/scilari/sas_cpp

This algorithm tries to create a distribution table, based on probability density function which is floating point. std::discrete_distribution takes integer weights, which means the distribution table has already been provided. It is a modern addition to the library, with a boost reference implementation; it is unlikely to be outperformed, in the absence of unconventional trade-offs for accuracy or other factors.

Weighted distribution requires list of ranges to check after a uniform distributed random number. If weights are 1,2,3,4,5 then by simply getting a random number between 0 and 15 and checking ranges (that is derived from a sum-scan) is enough:
1   2   3   4   5
0   1   3   6   10   15

if random number is 7 then its between 6 and 10 so the result is 4. Finding this range takes some time but can be optimized by using a tree.
(0-15)
 |     \
(0-6)   (6-15)
|    \       |\    
(0-3) (3-6)  | \
             () ()

this lowers the search complexity from O(num_ranges) to O(log(num_ranges)) plus the uniform random number generation. You can optimize the tree to have largest weights to be checked early (due to high possibility of occurence) by having them upper parts of tree.
C++ standard has this feature as std::lower_bound and std::distance. By lower_bound function there is the lower bound value of the range that integer is in and by distance function it returns the index value of the lower bound value which is the index of the weight itself. Complexity is O(log(N)) so having 100 items against 10 items should make it only 2x-3x slower instead of 10x.

magnitude of 0.1ms would be a great success.

For 10000 cycles of loop, this means 10 nanoseconds per iteration or very little time to traverse a large tree (like 10 depth). I'd expect somewhere around 100 nanoseconds per iteration, not a great success but is much faster than iterating whole list of weight-ranges for each input.
Also for brute-force checking whole list, parallel approach can still be fast with many cores. CPU with at least 100 cores would have results within communication latency time because of atomic incrementing some value, for 100 weights(1 per core). For 1 million weigts, a GPU-based (16k cores, 256k threads) approach is faster but has to compute multiple inputs at once due to kernel launch & sync latency.
